# Mapping XMLGregorianCalendar to Calendar with Dozer

Tags: java, date, calendar, dozer

**Prerequisites**

Dozer 5.5.1

**Code**

```
    public class Testdata {

            public static final Calendar CALENDAR_EXPECTATION;
            public static final XMLGregorianCalendar XMLGREGORIANCALENDAR_INPUT;

            static {
                    CALENDAR_EXPECTATION = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Paris"), Locale.GERMANY);
                    CALENDAR_EXPECTATION.clear();
                    CALENDAR_EXPECTATION.set(2015, 1, 2, 13, 15, 22);

                    XMLGREGORIANCALENDAR_INPUT = XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.createDateTime(2015,
                                                                                            1,
                                                                                            2,
                                                                                            13,
                                                                                            15,
                                                                                            22,
                                                                                            0,
                                                                                            (CALENDAR_EXPECTATION.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET)
                                                                                            + CALENDAR_EXPECTATION.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET))
                                                                                            / (60 * 1000));
            }
    }


    public class MappingTest {

            @Autowired
            private org.dozer.DozerBeanMapper dozerBeanMapper;

            private static x.y.z.ClassToMap classToMap;

            @BeforeClass
            public static void setupModel() throws Exception {
                    classToMap = new ClassToMap(Testdata.XMLGREGORIANCALENDAR_INPUT);
            }

            @Test
            public void testTransaktionsInfoToTransaktionsInfo(){
                    final x.y.MyMappedClass mapped =
                            dozerBeanMapper.map(classToMap, x.y.MyMappedClass.class);

                    compareCalendar(mapped.getMyCalendar(), Testdata.CALENDAR_EXPECTATION);
            }

            private void compareCalendar(Calendar ergebnis, Calendar erwartung) {
                    assertThat(ergebnis, notNullValue());
                    assertThat(ergebnis.get(Calendar.YEAR), is(erwartung.get(Calendar.YEAR)));
                    assertThat(ergebnis.get(Calendar.MONTH), is(erwartung.get(Calendar.MONTH)));
                    assertThat(ergebnis.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), is(erwartung.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
                    assertThat(ergebnis.get(Calendar.HOUR), is(erwartung.get(Calendar.HOUR)));
                    assertThat(ergebnis.get(Calendar.MINUTE), is(erwartung.get(Calendar.MINUTE)));
                    assertThat(ergebnis.get(Calendar.SECOND), is(erwartung.get(Calendar.SECOND)));
                    assertThat(ergebnis.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND), is(erwartung.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND)));
                    assertThat(ergebnis.getTimeZone(), is(erwartung.getTimeZone()));
            }
    }
```

**Problem**

The assert `assertThat(ergebnis.get(Calendar.MONTH), is(erwartung.get(Calendar.MONTH)));` fails.
The problem ist that the month in expectation is correct (1) but the mapped Calendar containts (0).

In org.dozer.converters.CalendarConverter following happens:

```
...
} else if (XMLGregorianCalendar.class.isAssignableFrom(srcFieldClass)) {
  Calendar c = ((XMLGregorianCalendar) srcObj).toGregorianCalendar();
  result.setTime(c.getTime());
  result.setTimeZone(c.getTimeZone());
}
...
```

Calendar c contains the wrong month (= 0). 
And the result after call result.setTime(c.getTime()); contains also month = 0.

Should I write my own converter to solve this?
And how to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For [`XMLGregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html), *January* corresponds to *1* and *December* corresponds to *12*, your test is OK so far:

> **month:** 1 to 12 or `DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED`

However, [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) has zero-based months, meaning that *January* corresponds to *0* and *December* corresponds to *11*.

> The first month of the year in the Gregorian and Julian calendars is JANUARY which is 0; the last depends on the number of months in a year.

In other words, your assertion is wrong. You are creating an `XMLGregorianCalendar` which has month *January*, and an assertion where you assume that it is *February*. The convert method in Dozer looks correct.

What you should do is to use the [constants](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#JANUARY) that `Calendar` provides, which makes it irrelevant whether the count starts with *0* or *1*:

```
CALENDAR_EXPECTATION = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Paris"), Locale.GERMANY);
CALENDAR_EXPECTATION.clear();
CALENDAR_EXPECTATION.set(2015, Calendar.JANUARY, 2, 13, 15, 22);
```